# Removing extra line in text file using perl

Tags: regex, perl

My processed log file has a extra line after each line.
ex:

```
abcd xyz
new line
lmno pqrst
new line
```

i want to remove this new line which is just space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in one line on the command line

```
perl -ne "print if /\S/" myfile > outfile
```